# iOS: Read real-time audio data from iTunes music track during playback

Tags: ios, visualization, itunes, audio-player

I'm working on a simple music player app for iOS that accesses the iTunes library. Now I want to add a small music visualization. Is it possible to access audio information like channel levels during playback?

I found a lot of information on how to visualize audio but in this special case I don't have an audio file to analyze so I'm kind of stuck...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access the currently playing audio data, if you don't have access to the file, via any public iOS API.  If your app does have access to the file, you might be able to convert it to raw PCM samples and play that as well as visualise it in your app.